# Good karma yields good results. What is role of GOD here?

Tags: gods, bhagavad-gita, vedanta, karma, spirituality

Good karma yields positive results, while bad karma leads to negative outcomes. Consequently, our experiences are shaped by our karma, prompting curiosity about the role of God in this process.

1. Can a person solely concentrate on cultivating good karma while disregarding God?
2. If the response to the 1st question is "NO," then what is the connection between karma, God, and the resulting consequences?
3. Why doesn't God force or motivate everyone to engage solely in good karma?

Comment: You don't really need god if you find the laws of Karma self-evident. This is why Ashtavakra Gita and Advaita Vedanta exist.

Answer (score 1):

**Can a person solely concentrate on cultivating good karma while disregarding God?**

If a person is not interested in moksha then yes he can solely concentrate on good karma.

**Karma can lead only to impermanent realm**

> One should understand that all the heavenly realms attained hereafter
> as a result of Karma performed now, are likewise impermanent. These
> heavenly regions are all relative like the principalities of petty
> chieftains, equalled by many and excelled by others, and all are
> liable to destruction alike in the end.

**Srimad Bhagavata Purana XI.3.20**

**If the response to the 1st question is "NO," then what is the connection between karma, God, and the resulting consequences?**

The response is 'yes' for a person who is not interested in moksha. The response is 'no' for a person interested in moksha. Moksha needs purification of heart.

**Mind causes both bondage and liberation**

> It is the view of wise men that the mind is the cause of both the
> bondage and liberation of embodied beings. If the mind is attached to
> the gunas of Prakriti and their products, it leads to bondage; but
> when it begins to feel delight and attraction for the Lord (Purusha),
> it leads to liberation. When the mind is freed from the impurities of
> lust and greed generated by the sense of ‘I’ and ‘mine’, it attains to
> purity and rests in equanimity, being unaffected by pleasure or pain.
> Then the Jiva, endowed with knowledge, renunciation and devotion,
> experiences in truth the Supreme Spirit transcending Nature (Prakriti)
> – Kevala (untouched by anything), eternal, self-effulgent, subtle,
> indivisible and unconcerned – as well as Prakriti with all its binding
> power destroyed.

Srimad Bhagavata Purana III.25.15-18

**Yoga practiced to purify the mind**

> For the attainment of mental purity, spiritual aspirants (Yogins)
> perform action devoid of attachment, with their body, mind, intellect
> or even merely with the senses.

**Gita 5.11**

A person who wants purification of heart can take help of God by practicing Bhakti Yoga or try to follow the path of vichar or self-enquiry by following the path of Jnana Yoga.

**Why doesn't God force or motivate everyone to engage solely in good karma?**

God doesn't normally interfere in the events of the universe.

The Lord does not normally interfere in the working of the universe although it is run by His power

> At the end of a cosmic cycle, O son of Kunti! All beings resolve into
> Nature (Prakrti), which is My own, and at the beginning of a new one
> (after the period of dissolution or Pralaya is over), I bring them out
> again.

**Gita 9.7**

> Resorting to Prakrti, Nature, which is My own Power, I send forth
> again and again this multitude of beings that are without any freedom,
> owing to Nature’s sway over them.

**Gita 9.8**

> These activities do not in any way bind Me, **because I remain detached
> like one unconcerned in their midst.**

**Gita 9.9**

> Under My direction and control, Nature brings out this mighty universe
> of living and non-living beings. Thus does the wheel of this world
> revolve.

**Gita 9.10**

Comment: Can you please references to : "f a person is not interested in moksha then yes he can solely concentrate on good karma."

Comment: I have already given the Bhagavata Purana reference that says that Karma leads to impermanent realm (and not moksha).

Comment: Okay, the error was on my side. I misread the quotes with bold ones and thought it wasn't with citations. The answer seems complete and I'm reversing the vote. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The role of GOD is to be the judge and the jury of your karma.

Answer (score 1):

God has no hand in giving you the results of your good and bad Karma. If you are a Bhakti oriented person, you want to do good Karma and offer it to God. You should do that, not to please God, but to do Niskam Marmayoga (meaning - Karma that joins you to God). If you are a Gyan oriented Hindu, you do not need belief in any God.

Answer (score 0):

There are certain schools of philosophy that exist within Hinduism that refute the idea of *eternal, self-caused, creator God*.

For example certain *samakhya* school philosophers propounded following arguments:

> 1. If the existence of karma is assumed, the proposition of God as a
>    moral governor of the universe is unnecessary. For, if God enforces
>    the consequences of actions then he can do so without karma. If
>    however, he is assumed to be within the law of karma, then karma
>    itself would be the giver of consequences and there would be no need
>    of a God.
> 2. Even if karma is denied, God still cannot be the enforcer
>    of consequences. Because the motives of an enforcer God would be
>    either egoistic or altruistic. Now, God's motives cannot be assumed
>    to be altruistic because an altruistic God would not create a world
>    so full of suffering. If his motives are assumed to be egoistic,
>    then God must be thought to have desire, as agency or authority
>    cannot be established in the absence of desire. However, assuming
>    that God has desire would contradict God's eternal freedom which
>    necessitates no compulsion in actions. Moreover, desire, according
>    to Samkhya, is an attribute of prakṛti and cannot be thought to grow
>    in God. The testimony of the Vedas, according to Samkhya, also
>    confirms this notion.
> 3. Despite arguments to the contrary, if God is
>    still assumed to contain unfulfilled desires, this would cause him
>    to suffer pain and other similar human experiences. Such a worldly
>    God would be no better than Samkhya's notion of higher self.
> 4. Furthermore, there is no proof of the existence of God. He is not
>    the object of perception, there exists no general proposition that
>    can prove him by inference and the testimony of the Vedas speaks of
>    prakṛti as the origin of the world, not God.

Reference: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samkhya#:~:text=If%20the%20existence,world%2C%20not%20God](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samkhya#:%7E:text=If%20the%20existence,world%2C%20not%20God).

A lot of texts on *Samakhya* philosophy - such as *Yoga Sutras of Patanjali* do refer to the *Ishvara*, but they don't mean them in terms of the dualistic philosophy of someone who is a great being - creator, organizer, or destroyer. Rather, they see them as an abstract representation of someone (**a special Purusha!**) who is a supreme ruler (or enforcer of karma), untouched by misery, actions and desires (Yoga Sutras of Patanjali: 1.24).

The end goal of *Purusha* is being realized as *self* (Samakhya Philosophy uses *Purusha-Prakriti* for such), hence **Ishvara** being realized as **self**.

---

In contrast, Adi Shankara's Advaitic philosophy has different views on this. **They believe *Ishvara* is an enforcer of *the laws of karma*.**

> Karma is insentient and short-lived, and cannot therefore be expected
> to bestow the fruits of actions at a future time according to one’s
> deserts. We do not see any insentient thing bestow fruits on those who
> worship it. Therefore it is only from the Lord, who is worshipped
> through actions, that their results proceed.

- Adi Shankaracharya (Src: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karma_in_Hinduism#:~:text=Karma%20is%20insentient,their%20results%20proceed.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karma_in_Hinduism#:%7E:text=Karma%20is%20insentient,their%20results%20proceed.))

This is clear from Shankara's commentary of Brahma Sutras III.2, 38, 41.

---

In contrast to all the above, certain Upanishads and Advaita Vedanta of pre-Shankara's era, do **NOT** believe in laws of karma. Breaking the bondage of karma is termed as: *liberation* or *nirvana*.

For laws of Karma to exist - *good* karma, as well as *bad* karma must also exist or there **must** be a distinction, so as to prove/disprove them.

> Right and wrong, pleasure and pain, exist in mind only. They are not
> your concern. You neither do nor enjoy. You are free.

~ Ashtavakra Gita 1.6

They further deny the existence of *prarabdha karma* which is considered most inescapable [karma from previous birth, yielding fruits in this birth].

> 28-29(a). So when he knows the eternal substratum of everything and
> all the universe becomes (therefore) void (to him), where then is
> Prarabdha to him, the body being a part of the world ? Therefore the
> word Prarabdha is accepted to enlighten the ignorant (only).

~ [Nada Bindu Upanishad](https://www.vedarahasya.net/nadabind.htm#:%7E:text=28%2D29(a).%20So%20when%20he%20knows%20the%20eternal%20substratum%20of%20everything%20and%20all%20the%20universe%20becomes%20(therefore)%20void%20(to%20him)%2C%20where%20then%20is%20Prarabdha%20to%20him%2C%20the%20body%20being%20a%20part%20of%20the%20world%20%3F%20Therefore%20the%20word%20Prarabdha%20is%20accepted%20to%20enlighten%20the%20ignorant%20(only).)

> Where is the unfolding of karma? Where is liberation in life, or even
> liberation at death? There is only One.

~ Ashtavakra Gita (20.4)

---

In dualistic schools of thought, God or *Ishvara* is thought of as a supreme being who is the cause of Maya and also the dispenser of fruits of action, also the one who maintains the law of karma.

The ultimate goal of dualistic schools is to get over the effects of the material world and karma (both good and bad), by focusing their bhakti on *Ishvara* or *God*, hence breaking the laws of karma for them and bringing liberation. Apart from that, *Ishvara* is also known to reduce the intensity of karma when a devotee is absorbed in *bhakti*. This is evident from:

> BG 3.9: Work must be done as a yajna to the Supreme Lord; otherwise,
> work causes bondage in this material world. Therefore, O son of Kunti,
> for the satisfaction of God, perform your prescribed duties, without
> being attached to the results.

~ Bhagavad Gita (3.9)
The bhakti to Ishvara, helps the devotee to cease bondage to the material world and, hence get liberated from the material world.

---

In other schools of philosophy like - Jainism and Buddhism too accept laws of karma evident at multiple places without having Ishvara or God.

Answer (score -1):

Thought provoking 3 questions:

```
   ACTIONS LEAD TO BONDAGE
```

There is an indirect answer only: Kriyaa is seen good by more persons, the same kriyaa is seen bad by some more persons. There are lots of examples in world.

Kriyaa s lead to Karma ending in good or bad either as convincing/against Supreme governing souls (PARAMAATMAA).

```
        WAVERING MIND
```

Those with wavering mind turn dictators(may be of any religion/community), try by their actions to overpower others by force or repetitive or noisy torture cannot realise God. For them God is of no use.

```
   FOLLOWERS OF VARNAASHRAMAA
```

Hence, to surrender our Karmas to God irrespective of bad or good(based on people groups), God is required. If Karma is good God accepts our souls. If Karma is bad one has to repeat life stories till he/she reaches liberation. These are called cycles of testimony in an ocean: SAMSAARA SAAGARA which is far better than DEMONAIC HELL & BHOOTA LOKAA.